# Select rows which contains a specific number after current date

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to select rows which contains a specific number after current date.

My code looks like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTableName
WHERE ( _001 ) AND My Date Column > todays date
LIKE '%2%'
```

I'm looking for the number 2 in _001.
"My Date Column" is describing the date linked the row.

Comment: Can you provide sample data and desired results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you describe it, the code would look like:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTableName
WHERE  `_001` = 2 AND datecol > CURDATE();
```

Note that `now()` contains a time component, which can throw off logic (although it would probably work in this context).

Answer (score 1):

you can use `SUBSTR` function for it, like this - 
`SELECT * FROM MyTableName WHERE SUBSTR(your-date-col,0,1) = '2' AND your-date-col > CURDATE()`

Answer (score 0):

use MySQL `CURDATE()`

```
Date > CURDATE() //return current date
```

or try this query :-

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTableName
WHERE ( _001 ) AND date > CURDATE()
LIKE '%2%'
```